# Usage of velocity for plugin development

Tags: java, velocity, intellij-plugin

**Edit**

Downvoter, how is this a bad question? I faced this issue because of classpath loaders required by velocity

Idea is to create a predefined java class based on configuration through UI.
Created an Action which pops up UI to get the configuration.
The predefined java custom code is stored as a velocity template inside plugin resources.
While using below code to load template it throws an error (**Resource Not found**)

```
VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class","org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
velocityEngine.init();
Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("EntityModel.vm");
```

Comment: Maybe the `StandardResource` extension point? (Mentioned on the [support platform](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002747599/comments/360000333459) which might be useful to you anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Used below methods to achieve the required result. velocity evaluate accepts velocity context, velocityTemplate file as Reader and to write output it requires a writer. The below function was useful to ignore the resource loader problems in any environment.

```
        VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
        velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
        velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
        velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM, new NullLogChute());
        velocityEngine.init();
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        context.put("fields",model.getFields());
        context.put("vFunction",new VelocityFunction());
        InputStream resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("EntityModel.vm");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(resourceAsStream);
        velocityEngine.evaluate(context, writer, "ERROR", inputStreamReader);
```